# Running HBase on top of Alluxio

Tags: hbase, alluxio

Has anyone succeeded running hbase on top of Alluxio?

There is no wiki on Alluxio's webpage related to this matter... No Lucky with the google result neither!

My Environment is:

- Hadoop 2.6
- HBase 0.98.20
- Alluxio 1.1.0

### Edit

`java.io.IOException: alluxio.exception.FileDoesNotExistException: Path /hbase/data/hbase/meta/.tabledesc does not exist` this is the best I got so far...

Comment: I figure it out....this is a bug in Alluxio 1.1.0 and has been fixed in 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT

Comment: There is now an official guide on alluxio.org: http://www.alluxio.org/docs/1.3/en/Running-HBase-on-Alluxio.html